# How to get only the last ul of specific id on page via CSS :last-child property?

Tags: css

My page generates two ULs of the same ID and I would like to remove the last one via CSS (display: none). I was trying with :last-child property but no luck at all. I either made both of them disappear or none of them.

Example:

```
<div id="content">

<ul id="some-ul">
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
</ul>

<ul id="some-ul">
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

I would like to apply display: none only for the last ul#some-ul inside my #content.

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely generic way to do this, that relies on no classes or ID's

```
div ul:last-of-type li:last-child {
    display:none;
}
```

So basically, the div is the parent item that contains the list items - it could have a class or ID if you want.

Within that, you have your ul tags - the last-of-type does the magic, finding the last ul within the parent div. You then simply use last child on the li.

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Kx8SN/

Comment: I would like to remove only the last ul which has an ID of "some-ul" if possible? Because the last ul on the page might be some other class or id and I don't want to have it removed. And also, I don't want to remove the last li but the last ul of the #content, the WHOLE ul, with all LIs inside.

Comment: Perhaps you need to explain what your trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

It could be done like so:

```
#content ul:last-child {
   display:none;
}
```

Note that `last-child` is only supported in IE9+. As mentioned by @Jop, you should set a class on the last child element to get around this for older versions of IE.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gxz8D/)

Also, remember that ID's should **always** be unique.

Comment: Please also note that :last-child is a css3 selector and thus will not work in older versions of IE. In this case you should set a class on the last-child to get this to work.

Comment: I know that IDs have to be unique, but my PHP generates it this way and I want to remove the last ul#some-ul from my code. I even tried something like you mentioned before: #content ul#some-ul:last-child {
    display:none;
}

Comment: @JayQuery `#content ul#some-ul:last-child { display:none; }`

Comment: @JayQuery Although the above will work, you should try to find a way to not generate duplicate id's.